# Ошибка вызова java метода из NDK кода

Tags: android, jni

Есть такой java код:

```
public class HelloJni extends Activity {
    public void on_connected(Boolean ok) {}
};
```

из NDK пытаюсь вызвать этот метод так:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
connect(JNIEnv *env, jclass) {
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/example/hellojni/HelloJni");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "on_connected", "(Z)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(cls, mid, (jboolean)false);
}
```

но получаю:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with
>   pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   no non-static method "Lcom/example/hellojni/HelloJni;.on_connected(Z)V"

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так?

И еще, не понятно, почему в сообщении об ошибке имя метода выглядит так(т.е. с точкой-запятой): `"Lcom/example/hellojni/HelloJni;.on_connected(Z)V"`

Comment: НЕ знаю почему, но если изменить тип переменной ok с Boolean на int и, соответственно, jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "on_connected", "(Z)V"); env->CallVoidMethod(cls, mid, (jboolean)false); на jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "on_connected", "(I)V"); env->CallVoidMethod(cls, mid, 0); то не падает

Comment: Z - это `boolean`, а не `Boolean`. Попробуйте заменить в Java части `Boolean` на `boolean` (то есть, на примитив).

Comment: @suvitruf, да Вы правы! Скорее всего у господина tasheehoobv именно в этом и была ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давно уже с jni не работал, но, если мне память не изменяет, то в имени метода в jni части должен быть полный путь. То есть, в вашем случае:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_connect(JNIEnv *env, jclass) {
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/example/hellojni/HelloJni");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "on_connected", "(Z)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(cls, mid, (jboolean)false);
}
```

`connect` же метод класс `HelloJni`?

Плюс, в вашем случае это будет работать только в пределах метода. При обращении к ссылкам вне этого метода, там будут `NULL`'ы. Лучше получать ссылку на `JVM` через `env->GetJavaVM(&mJVM)`, если в будущем хотите вызывать этот метод вне `com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_connect`.

Я написал в своё время [статью](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/03/03/3081/) про это. Думаю, ещё актуальна.

**Also**, Z - это `boolean`, а не `Boolean`. Попробуйте заменить в Java части `Boolean` на `boolean` (то есть, на примитив).

Comment: да, по поводу `com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_connect` - вы правы. я укоротил имя в примере. по поводу статьи - спасибо!